# Regex any character except one word

Tags: regex

How can I define a regex group for any characters except one word?

I know there are several similar questions already asked, but could not find the way to do that within a complex regex:

My regex Looks like this:

```
...(?<Subfield7>.{1,16})(?<Subfield8>//.{1,16})?
```

Where Subfield7 should match anything except the two forward slashes, because they are the separator for the next subfield.

> - ...**abcdefghijklmnop**//abcdefghijklmnop -> Subfield 7: abcde..., Subfield 8: //abcde...
> - ...**1.3,5-7 9/11**//abcdefghijklmnop -> Subfield 7: 1.3,5-7 9/11, Subfield 8: //abcde...
> - ...**12345**//abc//123//456 -> Subfield 7: 12345, Subfield 8: //abc//123//456

**Edit:**
My goal was to identify subfield 7 and subfield 8. Where by definition Subfield 8 starts with two leading slashes but subfield 7 might also contain (single) slahses. Lenght of subfield 7 and 8 are variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any non-empty string without `//` you may use

```
"(?!.*//).{1,16}"
```

This matches **/a** and **/** and does not match **//a** or **//** or **a//b**.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi. Many Thanks. This works when used as a single regex. But when followed by the next pattern ((?<Subfield8>//.{1,16})?), the regex fails. This is because by Definition the the Subfield 8 starts with two slashes.